# separating string text by "|" doesn't work

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I have a variable, whose value is in string form and looks like this:

```
test_intro|test_wm02|test_wf06|test_lf10|t ....
```

When I use this command:

```
strsplit(df$var,"|")
```

I get the following output:

```
"t" "e" "s" "t" "_" "i" "n" "t" "r" "o" "|" "t" "e" "s" "t" "_" "w" "m" "0" "1" "|" "t" "e ....
```

which makes me think that there's something wrong with the syntax. Would appreciate if someone could point to where the problem might be?

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question and add the programming language you are running. Also take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/215552)

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: shouldn't it split by where the "|" apears? and not every alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that `fixed` is `TRUE`:

```
strsplit(df$var, "|", TRUE)
```

Output:

```
"test_intro" "test_wm02"  "test_wf06"  "test_lf10"  "t ...."
```

If `fixed` is default (`FALSE`) then the `split` expression will be treated as a *regular expression*.  Instead, you want to split by the exact character `|`, so `fixed` must be `TRUE`.

Comment: Ah, this is it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a more robust answer here because `fixed = TRUE` may fix this problem, but can cause other problems. The problem here is that the `|` character means "or" in Regex. So you are saying to split the string on blank or blank. Splitting on blank is a special feature in strsplit that intentionally divides a string into its character components (which is REALLY useful sometimes).

Instead of using the `fixed = TRUE` argument you can write you splitting character in Regex format. In R that means you will need a double escape.

```
test <- "test_intro|test_wm02|test_wf06|test_lf10|t ...."

# The following doesn't work as expected because | is an or character in regex.
strsplit(test,"|")
# [1] "t" "e" "s" "t" "_" "i" "n" "t" "r" "o" "|" "t" "e" "s" "t" "_" "w" "m" "0" "2" "|" "t" "e" "s" "t" "_" "w" "f" "0"
# [30] "6" "|" "t" "e" "s" "t" "_" "l" "f" "1" "0" "|" "t" " " "." "." "." "."

# Escaping the | character (see regex manual) will make the code work as expected
strsplit(test,"\\|")
# [1]  "test_intro" "test_wm02"  "test_wf06"  "test_lf10"  "t ...."
```

Comment: This is much more reliable and consistent than setting fixed = TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the pipe in JavaScript, you can do this:

```
let str = "test_intro|test_wm02|test_wf06|test_lf10|t ....";
str.split("|");
// returns an array of your string broken up, without the pipe`
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I should have clarified, this is in R. I edited the question a bit!!

Comment: Ok try this link:

https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-split-strings-in-r/

`strsplit(YOURVARIABLE, "|")`

Comment: @ReenaVerma That is exactly what OP is already doing in their code... It's not working because it's using a regular expression instead of a fixed string

Comment: Thank you :) I don't know R, but thought I would try and dig out a helpful link :)